# Azure DevOps - App Service - Parallel Slot Swap

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

This [Deploy Task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureAppServiceManageV0/README.md) is super cool. I want to do two at once. Is there a way to do this via DevOps tasks? If not are there any know work-arounds? I tried this with Azure PowerShell but the commands didn't fire, even though it works locally :(

```
Start-Job -Name API {
    #Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot -SourceSlotName "staging" -DestinationSlotName "production" -ResourceGroupName "CoolResGroup" -Name "something-api-east"
}

Write-Host "API Staging <-> Prod swap initiated"

Start-Job -Name Web {
    #Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot -SourceSlotName "staging" -DestinationSlotName "production" -ResourceGroupName "CoolResGroup" -Name "something-web-east"
}

Write-Host "Web Staging <-> Prod swap initiated"

Wait-Job -Name API
Wait-Job -Name Web

If (Get-Job -Name API -ea silentlycontinue)
{
    Write-Host "API state: $((Get-Job -Name API).State)"
} 
Else 
{
    Write-Host "API slot swap complete."
}

If (Get-Job -Name Web -ea silentlycontinue)
{
    Write-Host "Web state: $((Get-Job -Name Web).State)"
} 
Else 
{
    Write-Host "Web slot swap complete."
}
```

Comment: define two at once? just add the same task second time and configure it?

Comment: That will execute each serially. I've done this and it's working, but I'd like to swap both the website and API app services at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default those powershell cmdlets are blocking, so you either need to start them in a background thread, or convert them to API calls (they shouldn't be blocking). This way you can perform those 2 calls more or less at the same time.

This would, however, complicate your flow, as you'd need to detect if both swaps completed fine (so an extra check you'd need to make).

Alternatively you are better of using A\B deployments. Links:  https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABTestingAndTestingInProductionWithAzureWebApps.aspx
http://involvenevolve.com/post/managing-azure-app-service-routing-rules/
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cli/azure/webapp/traffic-routing?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-traffic-routing-set

Comment: If I did A|B deployments, I'd still have two app services that'd need to have their traffic percentages switched simultaneously, right? I'd have to tell the Web app service to put 100% of the traffic to the Staging slot, or whatever slot I choose. Then I'll need to do the same thing for API. Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: dont put 100%, put 5%

Comment: Oooooh I get it. What a nice opportunity to switch to Blue/Green deployments!